# problem in run some js codes after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

why after search and click on result search and click on plus(button add input) in the example on part **Adding input**, Date formating(`$('.find_input').delegate('input.date:text', 'keyup', ....`) and normal number formatting(`$('.find_input').delegate('input.numeric:text','keyup',...`) not work.

EXAMPLE: http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign

Js full code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZpDDR/

```
...
///// Date formating /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $dateSet = 0;
    $monthSet = 0;
    $yearSet = 0;

    $('.find_input').delegate('input.date:text', 'keyup', function () {
        $val = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]+/g, "").match(/\d{1,12}$/);
        if($val == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            $val = $val.join("");
        }

        if($(this).val().match(/\d{4,}$/) && $val.length%2 == 0) {
            $val = $val.match(/\d{2}/g);
            if($yearSet < $monthSet) {
                if($val.length == 4) {
                    $(this).val($val.join("").replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/,'$3/$1/$2'));
                    $yearSet++;
                } else if($val.length == 6){

                    $(this).val($val.join("").replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/,'$4/$2/$3'));
                    $yearSet++;
                }
            } else {
                if($monthSet < $dateSet) {
                    $(this).val($val.join("").replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/,'$1/$4/$3'));
                    $monthSet++;
                } else {

                    if($val.length == 2) {
                           $(this).val($val.reverse().join("/"));
                        $dateSet++;
                        $monthSet++;
                    } else {
                           $(this).val($val.join("").replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/,'$1/$2/$4'));
                        $dateSet++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

///normal number formatting/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
    $('.find_input').delegate('input.numeric:text','keyup',function () {
        $val = $(this).val().match(/[0-9]/g).reverse().join("").match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",").match(/./g).reverse().join("");
        $(this).val($val)
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the element that you're delegating from,`.find_input`, doesn't exist yet when you're setting up the delegation function.  `delegate` allows for defining event handlers for elements that aren't created yet, but only elements that match the second selector E.g., `$('#must-exist-now').delegate('.can-be-created-later', ...);`

I'm not sure if I described that well, but the solution is to change your statement to delegate from something that already exists on DOM load.  For example: `$(document).delegate('input.date:text', ...)`.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's it doing now?  Can you show your latest code?

Comment: latest code in here http://jsfiddle.net/ZpDDR/1/ OR http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/files/js/admin.js

Comment: Your latest code is still using `$('.find_input').delegate(...)`.  Have you tried `$(document).delegate(...)` yet?